# Using Backbone model/collections without jQuery in webpack

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webpack

I'm learning React and am looking for a solid model system - something simplifies querying/posting to RESTful endpoints.

Backbome's collection/model functionality is exactly what I need, and their website indicates that jQuery is not required except for view-related code.

I'm using webpack, and including Backbone:

```
import Backbone from 'backbone`;
```

However, it's throwing errors about jQuery:

```
ERROR in ./~/backbone/backbone.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in node_modules/backbone 
@ ./~/backbone/backbone.js 18:4-22:6
```

No change if I limit my import to `Collection` or `Model`.

Is there any way around this - jquery is entirely unnecessary for my project and is a lot of bloat I don't want.

I'm not seeing any good alternative model/rest type libraries either...

Comment: I know this comment is a bit late in the game... but feel free to check out [js-data](http://www.js-data.io/). It's a frame-work agnostic model layer inspired by Ember Data. It can interface with a variety of storage layers, including RESTful backends.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the model use [backbone-model](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backbone-model). If you also want the collection, add [backbone-collection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/backbone-collection).

Comment: Looks like the right direction. I've filed an issue for backbone-model though because it fails to install - it requires backbone-helpers 1.0.6, which doesn't exist as far as I can find.